# How to programmatically set the transition style of a UIPageViewController in swift, Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to make a UIPageviewController programmatically without using the storyboard, I know that there is an option on the storyboard to set the transition style, but I won't be able to do this. I basically want to set the transition style to page scroll within the code.

I have tried many things, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in the initialization, before your `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
override init(transitionStyle style: 
UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
    super.init(transitionStyle: .whatever_style, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
}
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```